# THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I load obj and mtl files using three.js as like the code below, the following error appears.

```
            let scene, camera, renderer, orbitControls;

        function initThreeJS() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // 축 표시
            const axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(10);
            scene.add(axes);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1.0);
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(document.getElementById('myCanvas').clientWidth, document.getElementById('myCanvas').clientHeight);

            // 해상도 향상
            renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
            renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1.1;     // 밝기 조절


            document.getElementById('myCanvas').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            // 좌클릭 드래그 시, 아바타가 축을 기준으로만 회전하게 하려면 maxPolarAngle과 minPolarAngle의 값을 일치
            {#orbitControls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;#}
            orbitControls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
            orbitControls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;

            orbitControls.minDistance = 0.1;
            orbitControls.maxDistance = 100;
            {#orbitControls.autoRotate = true;#}
            orbitControls.autoRotateSpeed = 1.0;

            addLight(0, 50, 0, 0.7);    // 상단 빛
            addLight(0, -50, 0, 0.7);    // 하단 빛
            addLight(-50, 0, 0, 0.7);    // 왼쪽 빛
            addLight(50, 0, 0, 0.7);    // 오른쪽 빛
            addLight(0, 0, 50, 1);    // 전면 빛
            addLight(0, 0, -50, 1.0);    // 후면 빛

            animate();
        }

        function addLight(x, y, z, intensity) {
            // intensity: 빛 밝기 정도
            const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, intensity);
            light.position.set(x, y, z);
            scene.add(light);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            orbitControls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }


        function loadObj(url) {
            const objUrl = "{% static 'test3-1-2/test3-1-2.obj' %}"
            const mtlUrl = "{% static 'test3-1-2/test3-1-2.mtl' %}"
            // MTL 파일 로드
            const mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
            mtlLoader.load(mtlUrl, (materials) => {
                materials.preload();

                // 텍스처 필터링 설정
                for (let materialName in materials.materials) {
                    let material = materials.materials[materialName];

                    // 해상도 향상
                    // test1-5 렌더링
                    let newMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
                        map: material.map,
                        color: material.color,
                        transparent: true,      // 구두 굽 사이의 공간을 빈 공간으로 // 단점: 구두 근처가 흐릿하게 렌더링
                        opacity: 0.9
                     });
                    materials.materials[materialName] = newMaterial;        // 재질 교체
                }

                // OBJ 파일 로드
                const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.load(objUrl, (object) => {
                    object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);


                    scene.add(object);
                }, undefined, (error) => {
                    console.log('OBJ Load error: ', error.message, error.stack)
                })
            }, undefined, (error) => {
                console.log('MTL Load error: ', error.message, error.stack)
            })
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initThreeJS);
```

> THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.

If you open and check the obj file with a 3D program, you can see the problem with the obj file. What should I do?

Please help!

Comment: Do you mind sharing one of the problematic OBJ files in this thread?